# Changes to a Gmail notification script

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

After a long search I've found [this python script](https://github.com/gevermann/gmail-iphone-push/blob/master/server/server.py) that does what I need in order to get a real time notification to my iOS app when a new email arrives. I usually write in Objective-c and this is the first time I'm dealing with `Python`. Before I'll try to setup and run the script I'd like to understand it a bit better.

This is the part that I'm not sure about:

```
# Because this is just an example, exit after 8 hours
time.sleep(8*60*60)

#finally:
# Clean up.
idler.stop()
idler.join()
M.close()
# This is important!
M.logout()
```

My questions:

1. Should I comment out `time.sleep(8*60*60)` If I want to keep the connection active at all times?
2. What's the use for the Clean up section? Do I need it if I want to keep the connection?
3. Why `M.logout()` is important?

The main question that includes all the above is What changes (if any) I need to do to this script in order for it to function without stoping or timing out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script has started another thread, the actual work is done in this other thread.
For some reason the main thread is left without anything to do, that's why the author has put the time.sleep(8*60*60) to occupy it for a while.

If you want to keep the connection active at all times you need to uncomment the `try:`/`finally:`, see bellow.

If you are new to python beware that indentation is used to define blocks of code. The cleanup part might actually not be useful if you don't plan to stop the program, but with the `try:`/`finally:` the cleanup code will be executed even if you stop the program with Ctrl+C.

Not tested:

```
# Had to do this stuff in a try-finally, since some testing 
# went a little wrong.....
try:
    # Set the following two lines to your creds and server
    M = imaplib2.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
    M.login(USER, PASSWORD)
    # We need to get out of the AUTH state, so we just select 
    # the INBOX.
    M.select("INBOX")
    numUnseen = getUnseen()
    sendPushNotification(numUnseen)

    #print M.status("INBOX", '(UNSEEN)')
    # Start the Idler thread
    idler = Idler(M)
    idler.start()

    # Sleep forever, one minute at a time
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)

finally:
    # Clean up.
    idler.stop()
    idler.join()
    M.close()
    # This is important!
    M.logout()
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. So basically the `time.sleep(60)` will exit one thread that is no longer useful after a minute while another thread will still be in progress?

Comment: No, the `time.sleep()` function simply make the thread wait and prevent it from consuming cpu time. I have not implemented the cleanest solution here, it's just a way to fix your script with minimum changes.